# Data Lake -U SQL we need to create out Pramater( Outout File Name) with expression of UTC time Error Out

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

WE have  requirment to  gnerate output file with filename
for example "filename_utctime"

we run USQL from ADF

### below is USQL

```
    @Orders=
EXTRACT
 OrderID int,
    CustomerID int,
    OrderDetailID int,
    OrderTotal double,
    OrderDate DateTime

 FROM @IN
      USING Extractors.Csv();

@GetLatest=
SELECT 
      OrderID,
    CustomerID,
    OrderDetailID,
    OrderTotal,
    OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID,CustomerID,OrderDetailID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS Rid FROM @Orders;
@FinalOrder=
SELECT 
      OrderID,
    CustomerID,
    OrderDetailID,
    OrderTotal,
    OrderDate
    FROM @GetLatest WHERE Rid==1;
OUTPUT  @FinalOrder 
    TO @OUT
    USING Outputters.Csv();
```

---

Now in ADF, 
i have Pass two Paramters

```
  "parameters": {
                    "IN": "/OrderDump/Orders.csv",
                    "OUT": {
                        **"value": "/OrderDump/formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')",**
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
```

But it's not working and give errors. i want to when output file gnerated with current date time

```
{ "errorCode": "2703", 
  "message": "Error Id: VertexFailedFast, Error Message: Vertex failed with a fail-fast error. ", 
"failureType": "UserError", 
"target": "Delata" }
```

Comment: I am change my ADF Pramaters                                                                      "parameters": {
                        "IN": "/OrderDump/Orders.csv",
                        "OUT": "/OrderDump/formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')"
                    }                                                                                                                                              but still i have same error

Answer (score 2):

In your ADF you should use @concat function. 
So your expression should look like

```
@concat('/OrderDump/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'.csv')
```